# Remove button shadow in java (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to remove shadow from a button. Since it is created in java (not in xml) I can't see the option to do so. I know the following line can be used in xml.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Tried the same in java as follows.

```
myButton.setStateListAnimator(null);
```

But the problem is, it will work only on devices with 21 API or above. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: By shadow do you mean elevation? and if so elevation is not present in devices below 21. And so, there will be no elevation on button for devices running <21. Did you run your code on <21 devices?

Comment: myButton.setBackground(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put

```
android:background="@null"
```

I mean

```
myButton.setBackground(null);
```

EDIT: Other possibilities (sorry for xml):

1. Set elevation as 0:

   `mybutton.setElevation(0);`
2. Set background as transparent:

   `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

   Check: [How to set transparent background for Image Button in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710025/how-to-set-transparent-background-for-image-button-in-code)
3. Set style to button:

   ```
       <Button
        ...
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
         ....
        />
   ```

   In Java code:

   ```
   Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext(), null, android.R.attr
           .borderlessButtonStyle);
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEndTime);
   ```

You may also visit: [Remove/add shadow effect dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930904/remove-add-shadow-effect-dynamically)

Comment: I need to do it in Java file. Tried myButton.setBackground(null), and no success.

Comment: try also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710025/how-to-set-transparent-background-for-image-button-in-code

Answer (score 0):

Use `Button.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int Color)` and set `radius` to `0`.